Golang: gorilla - how to handle requests to endpoint defined with url parameter when the parameter is empty
I have this endpoint definition:
router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(handlerNotFound)
router.HandleFunc("/customer/{id}", handlerCustUpd).Methods(http.MethodPut)

When called URL https://example.com/customer or https://example.com/customer it never reaches the handlerCustUpd where I could check for the existence nor the handlerNotFound nor it returns generic 404 Not Found error. It returns Error: socket hang up because the server fails with this:
http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:60440: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string\ngoroutine 132 [running]:\nnet/http.(*conn).serve.func1()\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1903 +0xbe\npanic({0xc05d3a0?, 0xc000c78420?})\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132\nbackend/vendors/nexuri.handlerNotFound({0xc11b4f0, 0xc000c36460}, 0xc000c166c0)\n\t/Users/tku/Data/Projects/nexuri/nexuri-backend/backend/vendors/nexuri/handlers-general.go:38 +0x346\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000c165a0?, {0xc11b4f0?, 0xc000c36460?}, 0xc00001b908?)\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2171 +0x29\ngithub.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc000180240, {0xc11b4f0, 0xc000c36460}, 0xc000c16480)\n\t/Users/tku/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.1/mux.go:212 +0x1e2\ngithub.com/gorilla/handlers.(*cors).ServeHTTP(0xc000194b40, {0xc11b4f0, 0xc000c36460}, 0xc000c16480)\n\t/Users/tku/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/handlers@v1.5.2/cors.go:54 +0x335\nnet/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc119df0?}, {0xc11b4f0?, 0xc000c36460?}, 0x6?)\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:3142 +0x8e\nnet/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002785a0, {0xc11ca80, 0xc0000f0db0})\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2044 +0x5e8\ncreated by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 78\n\t/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:3290 +0x4b4"

Any idea, how to:

Make the server to call the handler, where I can check the availability of the url param
Make the server to respond to malformed request (with not existing endpoint) with 404 Not Found
Make the server to call the handlerNotFound
Just make the server not to panic and respond with something reasonable

The only thing I could figure out was to have explicit endpoint for PUT: /customer and check for this. This is possible with a few endpoints but completely impossible with 100s of endpoints.
I tried to research the next and documentation of gorilla package and also tried ChatGPT. ;)
Thanks in advance!

It is not going to call handlerCustUpd because the path pattern does not match the pattern assigned to that handler. Looks like the panic is coming from the handlerNotFound function.

You could use a dynamic parameter e.grouter.HandleFunc("/customer{id:.*}", handlerCustUpd).Methods(http.MethodPut) and strip the leading forward slash on the matched id value

Look up where in your code the panic happens and fix the error. The error is not related to routing.

@BurakSerdar you are right ... I missed that. I was using r.Context() in this handler, which was not set because the previous middlewares were not run and thus the context was not set.

The solution to this issue was pointed by @BurakSerdar.
The handlerNotFound is correctly processed but since I used context which had not been set (dure to not running middlewares - which is logical).
Removing this allowed to return custom response. In my case status 404 Status Not Found.
